# Non-english multi-codepoint alphabets

Tags: text-object

incorrect text in 3d view. [image: sample]

in the picture below - black text is the correct one. this is a language called tamil(thamizh) from India. ordering of code points is the problem here as you can see.

I do not know what goes on under the hood of font parsing. Is there way to workaround this. I work with a lot of text and most of the time. Please help me